# React Bootstrap Form Styling of input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am trying to style my form inputs in a way that on click the label(e.g username, email, password) would automatically move from the middle to the top left corner of the input field.

I am using react-bootstrap, bootstrap in react.js

```
<Form id="register-form" className="signup-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <FormGroup controlId="name" bsSize="lg">
              <p className="form-label" htmlFor="name">
                Full Name
              </p>
              <div className="input-field">
              <img 
                src="images/icons/name.svg" 
                className="input-field-image" 
                alt="organisation name" height="28" width="28"
              />
              <FormControl 
                autoFocus
                className="form-control-lg"
                name="name" 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="Name" 
                onChange={handleFieldChange}
                value={fields.name}        
              />
              </div>
              <span className="validation-message"/>
          </FormGroup>
</Form>
```

Currently, I have both placeholder and label but I would like to move the label inside the field and have this animation onClick.

also CodeSandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-roentgen-2tizc?file=/src/App.js